# Enriched locally presentable categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

Is there a standard reference for the theory (if it exists) of $\mathcal{V}$-enriched locally presentable categories? Here $\mathcal{V}$ is a cosmos. Does anything unexpected happens here in contrast to the case $\mathcal{V}=\text{Set}$ treated in "Locally Presentable And Accessible Categories" by Adamek & Rosicky? In particular I'm interested in the case $\mathcal{V} = \text{Cat}$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard reference is Max Kelly’s 1982 paper [“Structures defined by finite limits in the enriched setting”](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CTGDC/CTGDC_1982__23_1/CTGDC_1982__23_1_3_0/CTGDC_1982__23_1_3_0.pdf).

Perhaps the most unexpected thing is how well the theory works!

Comment: Well, the theory works pretty well, but there are many unexpected things that happen!

Answer (score 10):

The theory is also developed further in two papers by Borceux, Quinteiro and Rosický: *Enriched accessible categories* [MR1419612](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1419612) and *A theory of enriched sketches* [MR1624638](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1624638). In the second one they say that they are particularly interested in case $\mathcal{V} = \text{Cat}$ and that they "intend to study this in a further publication", but I don't know of such a publication.

Answer (score 4):

One remark about the standard theory of enriched accessible categories is that the enriching category $\mathcal{V}$ is typically assumed to itself be locally presentable. This ensures that for sufficiently large $\kappa$, there is a good notion of $\kappa$-small limits and $\kappa$-filtered colimits -- for instance, they should commute in $\mathcal{V}$ -- which makes for a good notion of "smallness" for $\mathcal{V}$-enriched categories.

In principle, though, one should be able to develop a theory of $(\mathcal{V},\Phi)$-accessible categories based on any good duality between a class $\Phi$ of $\mathcal{V}$-limits and a class $\Phi^\vee$ of $\mathcal{V}$-colimits that commute in $\mathcal{V}$. (By "good", I mean that a condition called [soundness](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sound+doctrine) should be satisfied.) Conceptually, it's not necessary for $\mathcal{V}$ to be locally presentable or for $\Phi$ to be the class of $\kappa$-small $\mathcal{V}$-limits. For example, in the [unenriched case](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00126-3), the duality between finite products and sifted colimits can be developed in perfect analogy to the theory of $\kappa$-accessible categories for fixed $\kappa$, and one recovers the usual theory of Lawvere theories. Some aspects of such a general theory of locally $(\mathcal{V},\Phi)$-presentable categories are touched on by [Lack and Rosický](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2578).

What's missing from this story is an interesting notion of "raising the index of accessibility". In the standard enriched setup, where $\mathcal{V}$ is locally presentable, we have (just like the unenriched case) a hierarchy of $\Phi$'s to use -- $\kappa$-small $\mathcal{V}$-limits for arbitrarily large $\kappa$ -- and interesting theorems to state that rely on letting $\kappa$ vary. I simply don't know any good examples of such a hierarchy of $\Phi$'s besides the standard ones to motivate the development of the sort of general theory I'm driving at.