# Accessible categories in enriched category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

I study some definitions of accessible category (see [1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+category)) and the applications of that notions; my question: exist a notion of accessible category in therm of enriched category theory? (in case of exist, what uses have?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is such a thing. Google for the papers "[a theory of enriched sketches](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1998/n3/n3.pdf)" and "[enriched accessible categories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700021900)", both by J. Rosický and others. (btw, it's a duplicate of [Enriched locally presentable categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53470/enriched-locally-presentable-categories) )

Comment: As mentioned in answers to the linked near-duplicate question, another key source is Max Kelly’s 1982 paper [Structures defined by finite limits in the enriched context](http://archive.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1982__23_1_3_0).